# How to write code for animation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, animation, symbolic-math

I am trying to display convergence of Bernstein polynomials in MATLAB using the inbuilt function bernstein which is overloaded with symbolic variables.
I wrote the following code which displays all bernstein polynomials in different figure windows.
I searched for animation on MathWorks website, being a beginner to MATLAB, I didn't find some simple function to do this.
Please help me with the code.
Thanks.

```
          syms x  
          axis tight  
          for k=1:10  
             figure  
             ezplot(bernstein(sin(x),k,x))  
          end
```

Comment: What do you want to animate?

Comment: I just want to show those polynomials moving and slowly getting closer and closer to function sin(x).

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. By calling `figure` at the start of each iteration, you always open a new figure window, so you end up with 10 figures. Use e.g. `figure(1)` to always use figure nr. 1, or even better first create a new figure using `h=figure;` and open that figure by `figure(h)`.
2. Now you won't see much, because the plots are generated very fast. Using the [`pause`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html) function, you can specify a delay between iterations, e.g. for 0.5s delay use `pause(0.5)`.

Put together, this gives the following code for your animation:

```
syms x
h = figure;
for k=1:10  
    figure(h);
    ezplot(bernstein(sin(x),k,x));
    pause(0.5);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are really good animation tutorials on the mathworks site.

http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/record-animation-for-playback.html

However, to get a head start, you can try copying this code and just pasting your own function inside the loop.

```
  for k = 1:16
    figure(1);  
    axis tight;

    plot(sin(k:0.1:k+(2*pi))); % replace with your function

    M(k) = getframe;
  end

fps = 10; % adjust this to change playback speed

movie(M,1,fps); % run this to play movie

%% Save the animation to avi file
writerObj = VideoWriter('test.avi');
writerObj.FrameRate = fps;
open(writerObj);
writeVideo(writerObj,M);
close(writerObj);
```

Change the value of fps to adjust the playback speed, and you can rerun the line `movie(M,1,fps);` anytime to replay the animation without generating all the frames again.  The last block of code saves your resulting animation to an AVI file with the specified framerate.